# Pasar ResultSet a un JSON en Java JSP

Tags: java, sql-server, json

Mi consulta es para saber cómo puedo pasar un ResultSet de SQLServer a JSON, ya que estoy trabajando con librerías en JavaScript (ChartJS) para generar gráficos para un dashboard y éste sólo lee datos en ese formato.

```
package DAO;

import conexion.Conexion;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class GraficaDAO {

    private static final Conexion con = Conexion.conectar();
    private static PreparedStatement ps = null;
    private static ResultSet res = null;

    public ResultSet reporteMensual(String mes) throws Exception {

        String sproc = "{call sp_EquiposMes (?)}";

        try {
            ps = con.getCnn().prepareCall(sproc);
            ps.setString(1, mes.toString());
            res = ps.executeQuery();

            while (res.next()){
                String equipos = res.getString(1);
            }

        } catch (SQLException ex) {

        } finally {
            try {
                if (res != null) {
                    res.close();
                }
                if (ps != null) {
                    ps.close();
                }
                con.cerrarConexion();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

Ese es el código de mi consulta, de momento la estuve almacenando en un String para corroborar si los datos llegan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando trabajes con tu capa de base de datos, en lugar de devolver un `ResultSet`, lo mejor es devolver un objeto o representación de la data que quieras trabajar, luego puedes transformar esa data como más te resulte.

En el caso de tu método `GraficaDAO#reporteMensual` lo mejor que puedes hacer es obtener los datos devueltos por el procedimiento almacenado en una lista y luego convertir esta lista en un objeto JSON (o cualquier otra cosa que necesites).

```
public class GraficaDAO {

    private static final String sproc = "{call sp_EquiposMes (?)}";

    //devuelve una lista, no el ResultSet
    //una vez que cierres la conexión a base de datos, el ResultSet
    //estará cerrado y no podrá ser usado
    public List<ResultadosGrafico> reporteMensual(String mes) {
        List<ResultadosGrafico> lista = new ArrayList<>();

        //todos los elementos de conexion a base de datos deben estar
        //en el menor alcance posible para el metodo
        Conexion con = Conexion.conectar();
        //siempre dentro de un bloque try con recursos
        //automáticamente llamará al método close de los
        //recursos abiertos dentro de los "parámetros" del try
        //disponible desde Java 7
        try (Connection conn = con.getCnn();
            //para invocar procedimientos almacenados en Java
            //conviene usar CallableStatement
            CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall(sproc);) {
            //mes ya es un String, no tienes que llamar a su método toString
            cs.setString(1, mes);
            try (ResultSet res = cs.executeQuery()) {
                while (res.next()) {
                    //parsea el resultado de cada fila del ResultSet
                    ResultadosGrafico rg = new ResultadosGrafico();
                    //en lugar de usar el número de columna, mejor usa el nombre de la columna que se ha devuelto
                    rg.setAtributo1(res.getString("columna1"));
                    rg.setAtributo2(res.getString("columna2"));
                    //etc...

                    //importante: agregar este elemento en tu lista
                    lista.add(rg);
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            //por lo menos debes loguear esta excepción
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return lista;
}
```

Luego, puedes usar una librería como [JSON.org](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java) para convertir la lista `List<ResultadosGrafico>` a una cadena JSON. Pero esto es demasiado trabajo. Lo mejor es usar librerías como [jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) o [Google gson](https://github.com/google/gson) que hacen la conversión más simple y es más sencillo de mantener.

Siguiendo el diseño anterior y con una librería como jackson, puedes hacer como sigue:

```
public class ClienteReporteGrafico {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        //obtener la lista desde el dao
        GraficaDAO graficaDAO = new GraficaDAO();
        List<ResultadosGrafico> lista = graficaDAO.reporte();
        //jackson convierte tu objeto en json
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(lista);
        //pintamos el json en la consola para ver el resultado
        System.out.println(json);
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por la molestia Luiggi, me ayudaste demasiado :)

Answer (score 1):

Puedes Usar el siguiente código para crear un objeto json y luego ir agregando cada elemento del resultset al json.

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONException;

import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;

public class ResultSetConverter {
  public static JSONArray convert( ResultSet rs )
    throws SQLException, JSONException
  {
    JSONArray json = new JSONArray();
    ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();

    while(rs.next()) {
      int numColumns = rsmd.getColumnCount();
      JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

      for (int i=1; i<numColumns+1; i++) {
        String column_name = rsmd.getColumnName(i);

        if(rsmd.getColumnType(i)==java.sql.Types.ARRAY){
         obj.put(column_name, rs.getArray(column_name));
        }
        else if(rsmd.getColumnType(i)==java.sql.Types.BIGINT){
         obj.put(column_name, rs.getInt(column_name));
        }
        else if(rsmd.getColumnType(i)==java.sql.Types.BOOLEAN){
         obj.put(column_name, rs.getBoolean(column_name));
        }
        else if(rsmd.getColumnType(i)==java.sql.Types.BLOB){
         obj.put(column_name, rs.getBlob(column_name));
        }
        else if(rsmd.getColumnType(i)==java.sql.Types.DOUBLE){
         obj.put(column_name, rs.getDouble(column_name)); 
        }
        else if(rsmd.getColumnType(i)==java.sql.Types.FLOAT){
         obj.put(column_name, rs.getFloat(column_name));
        }
        else if(rsmd.getColumnType(i)==java.sql.Types.INTEGER){
         obj.put(column_name, rs.getInt(column_name));
        }
        else if(rsmd.getColumnType(i)==java.sql.Types.NVARCHAR){
         obj.put(column_name, rs.getNString(column_name));
        }
        else if(rsmd.getColumnType(i)==java.sql.Types.VARCHAR){
         obj.put(column_name, rs.getString(column_name));
        }
        else if(rsmd.getColumnType(i)==java.sql.Types.TINYINT){
         obj.put(column_name, rs.getInt(column_name));
        }
        else if(rsmd.getColumnType(i)==java.sql.Types.SMALLINT){
         obj.put(column_name, rs.getInt(column_name));
        }
        else if(rsmd.getColumnType(i)==java.sql.Types.DATE){
         obj.put(column_name, rs.getDate(column_name));
        }
        else if(rsmd.getColumnType(i)==java.sql.Types.TIMESTAMP){
        obj.put(column_name, rs.getTimestamp(column_name));   
        }
        else{
         obj.put(column_name, rs.getObject(column_name));
        }
      }

      json.put(obj);
    }

    return json;
  }
}
```

Comment: Cuidado. Si se agrega este método tal cual, va a fallar puesto que al llamar al método `GraficaDAO#reporteMensual` el `ResultSet` devuelto ya estará cerrado.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta Efren Narvaez :D