# java.lang.NullPointerException en JSP con SQL Server

Tags: java, sql-server, jsp, date

Estoy desarrollando un cuadro de mando, donde hice el siguiente procedimiento almacenado:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_reporteSemana @FECHA DATE
AS

DECLARE @INICIO_SEMANA AS DATE
DECLARE @MARTES AS DATE
DECLARE @MIERCOLES AS DATE
DECLARE @JUEVES AS DATE
DECLARE @VIERNES AS DATE
DECLARE @SABADO AS DATE
DECLARE @FIN_SEMANA AS DATE

SET @INICIO_SEMANA = CAST(DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0, @FECHA), 0) AS DATE)
SET @MARTES = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @INICIO_SEMANA)
SET @MIERCOLES = DATEADD(DAY, 2, @INICIO_SEMANA)
SET @JUEVES = DATEADD(DAY, 3, @INICIO_SEMANA)
SET @VIERNES = DATEADD(DAY, 4, @INICIO_SEMANA)
SET @SABADO = DATEADD(DAY, 5, @INICIO_SEMANA)
SET @FIN_SEMANA = CAST(DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0, @FECHA), 6) AS DATE)

;with cte as (
  SELECT a.OPER_CODIGO CODIGO,
         a.OPER_NOMBRE + ' ' + a.OPER_APEPATER + ' ' + a.OPER_APEMATER OPERARIO,
         CAST(c.TCKT_FFINAL AS DATE) FECHAS,
         COUNT(b.TCKT_NUMERO) CANTIDAD
    FROM OPERARIO a
    JOIN BITACORA b ON a.OPER_CODIGO = b.OPER_CODIGO
    JOIN TICKET c ON b.TCKT_NUMERO = c.TCKT_NUMERO
   WHERE CAST(c.TCKT_FFINAL AS DATE) BETWEEN @INICIO_SEMANA AND @FIN_SEMANA 
   AND (c.EST_CODIGO = 3 OR c.EST_CODIGO = 5)
   GROUP BY a.OPER_CODIGO,
            a.OPER_NOMBRE + ' ' + a.OPER_APEPATER + ' ' + a.OPER_APEMATER,
            CAST(c.TCKT_FFINAL AS DATE)
)
select codigo,
       operario,
       coalesce(sum(case when fechas = @inicio_semana then cantidad end),0) as lunes,
       coalesce(sum(case when fechas = @martes then cantidad end),0) as martes,
       coalesce(sum(case when fechas = @miercoles then cantidad end),0) as miercoles,
       coalesce(sum(case when fechas = @jueves then cantidad end),0) as jueves,
       coalesce(sum(case when fechas = @viernes then cantidad end),0) as viernes,
       coalesce(sum(case when fechas = @sabado then cantidad end),0) as sabado,
       coalesce(sum(case when fechas = @fin_semana then cantidad end),0) as domingo
  from cte
 group by codigo, operario
 order by codigo, operario;
GO
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Recibe como parametro una fecha del formato DATE "20161201", este SP me arroja una matriz que quiero mostrar en mi JSP.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy usando la librería de DatePicker Bootstrap para las fechas, pero de momento estoy mostrando la matriz con una fecha fija, ya que aún no averiguo como formatear una fecha "dd-mm-yyyy" en java.

Cuando ejecuto el proyecto e ingreso al menú de Reporte Semanal, carga la matriz, pero el problema surge cuando cambio de opción e intento regresar a esta, ahí es donde arroja el siguiente error:

> type Exception report
>
> messageInternal Server Error
>
> descriptionThe server encountered an internal error that prevented it
>   from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> root cause
>
> java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are
>   available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1 logs.

Adjunto los códigos:

DAO

```
package DAO;

import conexion.Conexion;
import java.sql.CallableStatement;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Vector;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class RecordSemanalDAO {

    private static final Conexion con = Conexion.conectar();
    private static ResultSet res = null;
    private static final String sproc = "{call sp_reporteSemana (?)}";

    private int codigo;
    private String nombre;
    private int lunes;
    private int martes;
    private int miercoles;
    private int jueves;
    private int viernes;
    private int sabado;
    private int domingo;

    public RecordSemanalDAO() {
    }

    public RecordSemanalDAO(int codigo, String nombre, int lunes, int martes, int miercoles, int jueves, int viernes, int sabado, int domingo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.lunes = lunes;
        this.martes = martes;
        this.miercoles = miercoles;
        this.jueves = jueves;
        this.viernes = viernes;
        this.sabado = sabado;
        this.domingo = domingo;
    }

    public static Vector ReporteSemanal(String fecha) {
        Vector reporte = null;
        try (Connection conn = con.getCnn();
                CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall(sproc);) {
            cs.setString(1, fecha);

            reporte = new Vector();

            try (ResultSet res = cs.executeQuery()) {
                while (res.next()) {
                    reporte.add(new RecordSemanalDAO(res.getInt(1), res.getString(2), res.getInt(3), res.getInt(4), res.getInt(5), res.getInt(6), res.getInt(7), res.getInt(8), res.getInt(9)));
                }
                return reporte;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.getLogger(RecordSemanalDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
        } finally {
            try {
                if (res != null) {
                    res.close();
                }
                con.cerrarConexion();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public int getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }

    public void setCodigo(int codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public int getLunes() {
        return lunes;
    }

    public void setLunes(int lunes) {
        this.lunes = lunes;
    }

    public int getMartes() {
        return martes;
    }

    public void setMartes(int martes) {
        this.martes = martes;
    }

    public int getMiercoles() {
        return miercoles;
    }

    public void setMiercoles(int miercles) {
        this.miercoles = miercles;
    }

    public int getJueves() {
        return jueves;
    }

    public void setJueves(int jueves) {
        this.jueves = jueves;
    }

    public int getViernes() {
        return viernes;
    }

    public void setViernes(int viernes) {
        this.viernes = viernes;
    }

    public int getSabado() {
        return sabado;
    }

    public void setSabado(int sabado) {
        this.sabado = sabado;
    }

    public int getDomingo() {
        return domingo;
    }

    public void setDomingo(int dmingo) {
        this.domingo = domingo;
    }
}
```

Página JSP

```
<%@page import="java.util.Vector"%>
<%@page import="DAO.RecordSemanalDAO"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <%@include file="../WEB-INF/jspf/jscss.jspf" %>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css"/>
        <title>Inkafarma - Dashboard</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2 sidebar">
                    <img src="img/perfil.png" class="img-circle" alt="Responsive image" id="imagen">
                    <h3 class="text-center nombre">Wilfredo Roel</h3>
                    <h4 class="text-center apellidos">Pedroso Melgarejo</h4>
                    <br>
                    <ul class="botones">
                        <a href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/index.do?op=index"><li class="activado"><i class="icono izquierda fa fa-home"></i>Inicio</li></a>
                        <br>
                        <a><li><i class="icono izquierda fa fa-arrow-up"></i>Records<i class="icono derecha fa fa-chevron-down"></i></li></a>
                        <ul>
                            <a href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/index.do?op=reporteSemanal"><li>Record Semanal</li></a>
                            <a href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/index.do?op=reporteMensual"><li>Record Mensual</li></a>
                        </ul>
                        <br>
                        <a><li><i class="icono izquierda fa fa-bar-chart"></i>Balances<i class="icono derecha fa fa-chevron-down"></i></li></a>
                        <ul>
                            <a href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/index.do?op=ticketsTop"><li>Tickets Top</li></a>
                            <a href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/index.do?op=ticketsReportadosLocales"><li>Tickets Reportados Locales</li></a>
                            <a href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/index.do?op=ticketsReportadosArea"><li>Tickets Reportados Áreas</li></a>
                            <a href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/index.do?op=incidentesTop"><li>Incidentes Top</li></a>
                            <a href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/index.do?op=requerimientosTop"><li>Requerimientos Top</li></a>
                            <a href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/index.do?op=incidentesFueraSLA"><li>Inc. Top fuera del SLA</li></a>
                            <a href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/index.do?op=requerimientosFueraSLA"><li>Req. Top fuera del SLA</li></a>
                        </ul>
                        <br>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main">
                    <div class="row encabezado">
                        <img src="img/inkafarmaheader.png">   
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-3"> 
                                <label>Seleccione Fecha: </label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                <form class="form-inline" action="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/index.do?op=recordSemanal" method="post"> 
                                    <div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker" data-date-format="yyyymmdd">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fecha">
                                        <div class="input-group-addon">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Mostrar</button>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <br><br><br>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 table-responsive">                  
                                <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                                    <tr class="success">
                                        <th class="text-center">Código</th>
                                        <th class="text-center">Operario</th>
                                        <th class="text-center">Lunes</th>
                                        <th class="text-center">Martes</th>
                                        <th class="text-center">Miércoles</th>
                                        <th class="text-center">Jueves</th>
                                        <th class="text-center">Viernes</th>
                                        <th class="text-center">Sábado</th>
                                        <th class="text-center">Domingo</th>
                                    </tr>

                                    <%
                                        RecordSemanalDAO objRec = new RecordSemanalDAO();
                                        Vector record = new Vector();
                                        record = RecordSemanalDAO.ReporteSemanal("20161201");
                                        for (int i = 0; i < record.size(); i++) {
                                            objRec = (RecordSemanalDAO) record.get(i);
                                    %>

                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="text-center active"><%=objRec.getCodigo()%></td>
                                        <td class="active"><%=objRec.getNombre()%></td>
                                        <td class="text-center"><%=objRec.getLunes()%></td>
                                        <td class="text-center"><%=objRec.getMartes()%></td>
                                        <td class="text-center"><%=objRec.getMiercoles()%></td>
                                        <td class="text-center"><%=objRec.getJueves()%></td>
                                        <td class="text-center"><%=objRec.getViernes()%></td>
                                        <td class="text-center"><%=objRec.getSabado()%></td>
                                        <td class="text-center"><%=objRec.getDomingo()%></td>
                                    </tr>  
                                    <%
                                        }
                                    %>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br><br>
                    <script src="js/main.js"></script>                 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Stacktrace:

> Grave:   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: La conexión
>   está cerrada.     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:191)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.checkClosed(SQLServerConnection.java:395)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.prepareCall(SQLServerConnection.java:2302)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.prepareCall(SQLServerConnection.java:1939)
>     at DAO.RecordSemanalDAO.ReporteSemanal(RecordSemanalDAO.java:47)    at
>   org.apache.jsp.reportes.reporteSemanal_jsp._jspService(reporteSemanal_jsp.java:197)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:411)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:473)
>     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:377)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:875)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:739)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:575)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:546)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:428)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:378)
>     at controlador.index.processRequest(index.java:35)  at
>   controlador.index.doGet(index.java:102)   at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
>     at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> Advertencia:   Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.apache.jsp.reportes.reporteSemanal_jsp._jspService(reporteSemanal_jsp.java:198)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:411)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:473)
>     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:377)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:875)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:739)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:575)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:546)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:428)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:378)
>     at controlador.index.processRequest(index.java:35)  at
>   controlador.index.doGet(index.java:102)   at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
>     at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> Advertencia:   StandardWrapperValve[index]: Servlet.service() for
>   servlet index threw exception java.lang.NullPointerException  at
>   org.apache.jsp.reportes.reporteSemanal_jsp._jspService(reporteSemanal_jsp.java:198)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:411)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:473)
>     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:377)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:875)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:739)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:575)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:546)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:428)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:378)
>     at controlador.index.processRequest(index.java:35)  at
>   controlador.index.doGet(index.java:102)   at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
>     at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Clase Conexión

```
package conexion;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Conexion {

    public static Conexion instance;
    private Connection cnn;
    private String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://Muse\\MSSQLSERVER:1433;databaseName=BD_INKAFARMA";
    private String driver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";
    private String usuario = "sa";
    private String pass = "rakel123";

    private Conexion() {

        try {
            Class.forName(driver);
            cnn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, usuario, pass);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Conexion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }

    public synchronized static Conexion conectar() {

        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new Conexion();
        }
        return instance;

    }

    public Connection getCnn() {
        return cnn;
    }

    public void cerrarConexion() {
        instance = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Lo primero que debe tratar es el problema de conexion que sale para la conexion Sql Server, puede que de ahi este todo el error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema tiene que ver con algo que vemos vez tras vez en diferentes preguntas por aquí: *el uso de una conexión en una variable global*:

```
public class RecordSemanalDAO {

    private static final Conexion con = Conexion.conectar();
```

Esta práctica tiene muchos problemas. Pero en tu caso específico, el error es causado porque abres la conexión *una sola vez* cuando se asigna la variable estática `con` en la sentencia anterior, pero la cierras a *cada llamada* del método `ReporteSemanal()`. De hecho lo cierras 2 veces a cada vez:

1. Al final del bloque `try (Connection conn = con.getCnn())`, la conexión se cierra autmáticamente
2. En el `finally` también ejecutas `con.cerrarConexion();` para énfasis :)

Código:

```
public static Vector ReporteSemanal(String fecha) {
    Vector reporte = null;
    try (Connection conn = con.getCnn();
            CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall(sproc);) {
        cs.setString(1, fecha);

        reporte = new Vector();

        try (ResultSet res = cs.executeQuery()) {
            while (res.next()) {
                reporte.add(new RecordSemanalDAO(res.getInt(1), res.getString(2), res.getInt(3), res.getInt(4), res.getInt(5), res.getInt(6), res.getInt(7), res.getInt(8), res.getInt(9)));
            }
            return reporte;
        }
    // 1. aquí se cierra, por estar al final del `try-with-resources`
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Logger.getLogger(RecordSemanalDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
    } finally {
        try {
            if (res != null) {
                res.close();
            }
            con.cerrarConexion(); // 2. Y aquí lo vuelves a cerrar.
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Eso quiere decir que uan vez que ejecutas el método `ReporteSemanal()` una vez, para las siguientes llamadas la conexión estará cerrada y te lanzará la excepción.

Un segundo problema es que estás tratando de manejar una excepción que en realidad no puedes manejar. Cuando se lanzó la excepción, la atrapastes y el método intentó continuar devolviendo un valor `null` al final. Eso es muy mal diseño, ya que inevitablemente, esto simplemente causa que vuelvas a tener un error mas adelante por no poder manejar el `null` correctamente.

De modo que la solución es

1. Eliminar esa conexión global (y de paso el `ResultSet` global también) y mas bien abrirla dentro del método mismo y asignarla a una variable local que puedes cerrar al concluir el método.
2. Eliminar los `try-catch` innecesarios. Si no puedes manejar una excepción, no trates de atraparla. Deja que la excepción siga subiendo la pila de llamadas.

Ejemplo de una versión mejorada y simplificada:

```
public static Vector ReporteSemanal(String fecha) {
    try (Connection conn = Conexion.conectar().getCnn();
            CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall(sproc)) {
        cs.setString(1, fecha);

        try (ResultSet res = cs.executeQuery()) {
            Vector reporte = new Vector();
            while (res.next()) {
                reporte.add(new RecordSemanalDAO(res.getInt(1), res.getString(2), res.getInt(3), res.getInt(4), res.getInt(5), res.getInt(6), res.getInt(7), res.getInt(8), res.getInt(9)));
            }
            return reporte;
        }
    }
}
```

Por suspuesto, pueden haber otras mejoras que puedas hacer, por ejemplo:

- Simplificar tu clase `Conexion`. no puedo ver su implementación, pero su uso, es casi seguro que necesita mejoras, ya que parece estar diseñada para maejar conexiones globales, lo que no es buena idea.
- Cambiar `Vector` por `ArrayList`. A menos que tengas una necesidad bien peculiar, `Vector` ya no se debería usar.

... pero estos son detalles menos importantes.

**Edición**

Resulta que ahora que has compartido tu clase `Conexion`, queda claro que allí tienes otro problema serio. Lo tienes definido como un singleton. O sea, que vuelves al mismo problema, porque en efecto tienes una sola conexión compartida, lo que no es correcto.

Te sugiero de modificar esa clase a algo simplificado como lo siguiente para eliminar el singleton.

```
public class Conexion {
    private static final String URL = "jdbc:sqlserver://Muse\\MSSQLSERVER:1433;databaseName=BD_INKAFARMA";
    private static final String DRIVER = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";
    private static final String USUARIO = "sa";
    private static final String PASS = "rakel123";

    static {
        try {
            Class.forName(DRIVER);
        } catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public static Connection conectar() {
        try {
            return DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USUARIO, PASS);
        } catch(SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Con esta clase modificada, tienes que hacer el siguiente ajusta a la sentencia con el `try`:

```
try (Connection conn = Conexion.conectar(); // quitar el .getCnn()
        CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall(sproc)) {
```

Comment: Esto ya lo había discutido con este usuario [en esta pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/q/42813/227). Al parecer redacto respuestas en vano...

Comment: @Luiggi: Ni tanto. Cuando vi la pregunta, me sorprendió ver un código que usara bien el patrón `try-with-resources`. Eso casi nunca se ve en las preguntas aquí. Pero al ver tu respuesta, ahora entiendo de donde salió. Así que, al menos parte de tu respuesta sobrevivió y sirvió. :)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza muchas gracias por tomarte la molestia de enseñarme, la verdad es que hay cosas que no sé porque soy estudiante aún. 
Estoy editando la pregunta agregando mi clase Conexion, ya que implementé el método que me facilitó sstan y aún sigue saliendo el mismo problema de conexión cerrada.

Comment: @Wil: Pues claro. Es que además de la variable global mencionado arriba, definistes la clase `Conexion` como un singleton. O sea que vuelve al mismo problema, porque allí también tienes una variable estática global que comparte una conexión. Hay que arreglar eso. Agregué una edición.

Comment: Solo agregaría que aunque compartir una conexión global definitivamente no es lo correcto, el abrir y cerrar una conexión cada vez que lo necesitas puede tener un cierto impacto en el rendimiento. Normalmente, lo que necesitas es usar un *connection pool*. Te sugiero investigar cómo puedes integrar uno con el driver que usas. Nota aparte, no creo que necesites la sentencia `Class.forName(DRIVER)`. Prueba sin ella para ver si todo funciona bien.

Comment: Muchas gracias! Me ayudaste demasiado al igual que @Luiggi, gracias, en serio les estoy muy agradecido!

Answer (score -1):

El error que te da es por la libreria Jasper reports. Revisa que no estes haciendo referencia a esta librería en tu código.

Para formatear una fecha en Java es muy sencillo. Simplemente tenes que usar la clase SimpleDateFormat. Ej:

```
public final class DateUtils {

public static String formatDate(Date fecha){
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy");
    return format.format(fecha);        
}

public static Date parseDate(String fecha) throws ParseException{
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy");
    return format.parse(fecha);        
}
```

}

Comment: Esto no tiene nada que ver. Más bien, esto significa que cuando Jasper genera el reporte, uno de los parámetros enviados posee valor nulo, por ende el error sale allí. ¿Cuál de los parámetros, en qué parte? Se necesita el stacktrace completo para conocer mejor estos detalles y saber cómo arreglarlo.

Comment: Porque me pones negativo? Si le estoy diciendo que el error viene por parte de Jasper.
El ejemplo de formatear es porque si lees toda su pregunta, tambien consulta como formatear una fecha.

Comment: Porque tu respuesta es incorrecta. Lee esta parte: "Revisa que no estes haciendo referencia a esta librería en tu código." ¿Esto significa que si una librería me da NPE debo dejar de usarla? ¿Significa que no estoy usándola mal, simplemente es defectuosa y no debo confiar en ella? ¿Aún a pesar que hay muchos proyectos que la usan, si a mí me falla entonces debo dejar de referenciar a la librería por completo porque me va a dar un NPE? ¿Eso es lo que intentas decir? ¿Y cómo se relaciona el NPE y Jasper con el formato de fecha?

Comment: Si quieres formatear una fecha, debe ser en el lado del cliente, tienes [`<fmt:formatDate>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fmt/formatDate.html) que ya usa un `SimpleDateFormat` al interno, no necesitas formatear la fecha desde el backend.